# How to convert timestamp into days in javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

i get endtimestamp as api response and i want calculate days from current time stamp.i have written one function for this conversion but give me worng result.

```
function timeDifference(current, previous) {

        var msPerMinute = 60 * 1000;
        var msPerHour = msPerMinute * 60;
        var msPerDay = msPerHour * 24;
        var msPerMonth = msPerDay * 30;
        var msPerYear = msPerDay * 365;
    
        var elapsed = current - previous;
    
        if (elapsed < msPerMinute) {
             return Math.round(elapsed/1000) + ' seconds ago';   
        }
    
        else if (elapsed < msPerHour) {
             return Math.round(elapsed/msPerMinute) + ' minutes ago';   
        }
    
        else if (elapsed < msPerDay ) {
             return Math.round(elapsed/msPerHour ) + ' hours ago';   
        }
    
        else if (elapsed < msPerMonth) {
            return '' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerDay) + ' days ago';   
        }
    
        else if (elapsed < msPerYear) {
            return '' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerMonth) + ' months ago';   
        }
    
        else {
            return '' + Math.round(elapsed/msPerYear ) + ' years ago';   
        }
    }
```

please suggest me right solution so i can get correct conversion

Comment: Consider appending sample input and respective output that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a library as moment.js
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/
Besides easier coding you won't get problems with leap years, leap seconds etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
function timeDifference(date) {
    var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
    if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*365.25)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*365.25)) + " years ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*365.25)) >= 1) return "1 year ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*30.4)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*30.4)) + " months ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*30.4)) >= 1) return "1 month ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*7)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*7)) + " weeks ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*7)) >= 1) return "1 week ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24)) + " days ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24)) >= 1) return "1 day ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60)) + " hours ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60)) >= 1) return "1 hour ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/60) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/60) + " minutes ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/60) >= 1) return "1 minute ago";
    else if(seconds >= 2)return seconds + " seconds ago";
    else return seconds + "1 second ago";
}
```

you can also use this plugin [javascript-time-ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-time-ago)

Answer (score 0):

i love reducing things, here is my solution.

```js
/**
 * @method msToTimeString : convert milliseconds to time string
 * @param {number} ms : milliseconds to convert
 */
const msToTimeString = ms => {
    const mods = [1000, 60, 60, 24, 365]; // time modulus
    const names = ["millisecond", "second", "minute", "hour", "day"]; // names
    return mods.reduce((acc, cur, index) => { // reduce modulus
        let unit = acc.val % cur; // calc current time scale
        acc.val = (acc.val - unit) / cur; // keep remaining
        acc[names[index]] = unit; // assign name to result
        return acc; // next
    }, {val: ms});
};

let past = new Date("2020-03-17T00:00:00").getTime(), // past date
    now = Date.now(); // now
    
let calc = msToTimeString(now - past);
console.log(calc.day, "days", calc.hour, "hours"); // also : calc.minute, calc.second, calc.millisecond
```

same code, savage one-liner

```js
/**
 * @method msToTimeString : convert milliseconds to time string
 * @param {number} ms : milliseconds to convert
 */
const msToTimeString = ms => {
    const names = ["millisecond", "second", "minute", "hour", "day"]; // names
    return [1000, 60, 60, 24, 365].reduce((acc, cur, index) => ({...acc, [names[index]]: acc.val % cur, val: (acc.val - (acc.val % cur)) / cur}), {val: ms});
};

let past = new Date("2020-03-17T00:00:00").getTime(), // past date
    now = Date.now(); // now
    
console.log(msToTimeString(now - past)); // display !
```